# For Loop not waiting for user input

Tags: java, android, loops

Hello i have an android project ongoing at the moment. The user must answer a maths question then point should be awarded/taken away for the answer then the code should display a second different question until 10 questions have been completed. The problem is that the code skips the loop and instantly finishes the game. I have attempted using a while loop but the same problem happened. I thought about an if but couldn't work out how to re run the if. Below is the whole code of the project but the main problem is the for loop.

```
package com.example.mixmathsv3;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.Random;

public class SimpleModeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button checkButt, nextQuestionButt;
TextView resultText, simpleQuestionText, scoreText, questionNumberText;
EditText userAnswer;

public volatile int completedTimes = 0;
public int scoreValue = 0;
public int intUserAnswer = 0;
public String questionAnswer = "";

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_mode);


    resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    checkButt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkButt);
    simpleQuestionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.simpleQuestionText);
    scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
    userAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userAnswer);
    //nextQuestionButt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextQuestion/Butt);
    //questionNumberText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionNumberText);





    final String[] questionArray = {"5+2", "10+3", "7+1", "9+0", "1+6"};
    final String[] answerArray = {"7", "13", "8", "9", "7"};
    final Random r = new Random();
    int arrayRandom = r.nextInt(questionArray.length);

    simpleQuestionText.setText(questionArray[arrayRandom]);
    questionAnswer = (answerArray[arrayRandom]);



    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        //System.out.println(i);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("loop successful"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        checkButt.setEnabled(true);


        checkButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkButt.setEnabled(false);

                intUserAnswer = Integer.parseInt(userAnswer.getText().toString());
                int intQuestionAnswer = Integer.parseInt(questionAnswer);


                if (intUserAnswer == intQuestionAnswer) {
                    resultText.setText("Correct");
                    scoreValue = scoreValue + 10;
                    //completedTimes = + 1;
                    //questionNumberText.setText(completedTimes);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("Your Score is " + scoreValue), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                if (intUserAnswer != intQuestionAnswer) {
                    resultText.setText("Incorrect");
                    scoreValue = scoreValue - 5;
                    //completedTimes = + 1;
                    //questionNumberText.setText(completedTimes)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("Your Score is " + scoreValue), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            }


        });

    }


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("Game Over"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: The answers you got point out your *real* problem:  lack of understanding how the Android framework works. Seriously: consider to **not** try to learn basic java together with Android. First learn enough Java to understand what the code you write down **basically** does. And then get good tutorials for specific problems with Android, and work with those. You are like a person who wants to learn to juggle ... while also learning to ride the unicycle. Dont do that. Otherwise you will walk from one frustrating moment to the next.

Comment: The problems with that this was a assignment set at college. He set it to us without teaching us java or proper android so it all had to be learned within the last couple of months. Yeah it has been frustrating as going from python to java without a teacher (corona) has been very hard

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but then you should really talk to your peers and your instructor. But beyond that: I still recommend then that you start by picking up android tutorials. Maybe stuff like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkUfACbi6BE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setOnClickListener` does not do what you think :
`setOnClickListener` is used to register a method that will be called **only** if the user click on the button.
In your example, the for-loop register 10 times a new `onClickListener` which is not what we want.

In your case, you must not use the for-loop which is executed instantly. Change the question and the text when the user clicked on the button.

```java
final String[] questionArray = {"5+2", "10+3", "7+1", "9+0", "1+6"};
final String[] answerArray = {"7", "13", "8", "9", "7"};
final Random r = new Random();
int answered = 0;
// Initial question
int arrayRandom = r.nextInt(questionArray.length);
simpleQuestionText.setText(questionArray[arrayRandom]);
questionAnswer = (answerArray[arrayRandom]);

checkButt.setEnabled(true);
checkButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void onClick(View v) {
        checkButt.setEnabled(false);

        intUserAnswer = Integer.parseInt(userAnswer.getText().toString());
        int intQuestionAnswer = Integer.parseInt(questionAnswer);

        if (intUserAnswer == intQuestionAnswer) {
            resultText.setText("Correct");
            scoreValue = scoreValue + 10;
            //completedTimes = + 1;
            //questionNumberText.setText(completedTimes);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("Your Score is " + scoreValue), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        if (intUserAnswer != intQuestionAnswer) {
            resultText.setText("Incorrect");
            scoreValue = scoreValue - 5;
            //completedTimes = + 1;
            //questionNumberText.setText(completedTimes)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("Your Score is " + scoreValue), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        answered++;// We update the count of answered question
        if(answered == 10) {
            // Finish
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("Game Over"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Change question
            int arrayRandom = r.nextInt(questionArray.length);
            simpleQuestionText.setText(questionArray[arrayRandom]);
            questionAnswer = (answerArray[arrayRandom]);
        }
    }

});
```

I suggest you to learn more about how Android is working and `callback` methods.

Comment: Thank you, This is logically more correct and i can now understand what you mean. Although this doesn't work implemented into my code i think this may be a more fundamental issue with the methods in my code. I will mark this one as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put everything in the loop. Move all logic outside the loop and it should work.

Comment: it works now, the code just doesn't do what the OP thinks it should do